# Emacs Helm (anything) colors for autocompletion

Tags: emacs

In helm-mode in Emacs, whenever `helm` tries to autocomplete what I am typing (e.g. with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> for `Find file`) I see that the options for autocompletion (files in this case) are colored differently (some in green, some with white background) etc.

What do these colors mean? How do I look them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out more about the helm faces just like any other Emacs buffer.

Put the point into the completion buffer by using the mouse of <kbd>C-x o</kbd>.

Then <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd>.  The faces at point will be shown.  Their names
should make it obvious what they mean, and you can follow the bread crumb to
customize them.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific file in helm where these faces are defined?

Comment: Clicking on the face name will show you where it's defined.  It may not all be in the same file.